# Как правильно делать запросы на сокет сервер?

Tags: javascript, php

У меня есть сокет-сервер на php, и я в js подключаюсь к нему и делаю определенные запросы, чтобы они в риалтайме выполнялись, и мне отсылался ответ. Иногда нужно, чтобы сервер сам отправлял мне сообщения, т.е. без моего запроса, поэтому ajax мне не подходит. И вот я делаю запрос таким образом:

```
let sendData = {
    type: 0,
    .. и какие-то параметры ..
};
```

Так вот `type` нужен, чтобы сервер понимал, что нужно с полученной информацией делать.
Например, если `type = 0`, то удалить пользователя с определенным именем, которое будет передано вместе с `type`:

```
let sendData = {
    type: 0,
    name: "Alex"
};
```

И принимаю я все ответы от сервера ровно таким же способом. Смотрю на `type` и понимаю, что делать. Такой метод я придумал сам, т.к. в первый раз работаю с сокет-сервером. Мне интересно, насколько такой подход правильный.

Comment: сокет-сервер = WebSocket server? php далеко не лучший вариант для такого... а в остальном.. в чем собственно вопрос?.. вы можете передавать и получать все что угодно

Comment: вопрос в том, правильно ли вообще так делать? А то любой сможет зайти в окно разработчика, найти js файл и спокойно отправлять любые запросы в websocket сервер

Comment: @ОсмановОсман, вообще в type можете передавать даже строку с названием команды, чтобы самому не путаться с цифрами. А вот на счёт того, что любой пользователь может отправить любой запрос на WebSocket server, для того чтобы вы смогли обезопасить вашу систему от таких "нежелательных запросов" вам следует делать конкретные валидации и мидлвейры (в принципе как и на обычном сервере протокола http(s)).

Comment: Верно, отправляйте все что угодно (в разумных приделах, 100 гб видос кидать не стоит), главное позаботьтесь об авторизации, валидации и тд.. к тому же, то, что отправляет клиент, уже принадлежит ему, как принять информацию ваша забота

Comment: Я понял теперь, как нужно сделать. Всем спасибо за ответы!

Comment: К выше сказанному.. я конечно не эксперт, но, делать такой сервис на php - геморой... вы уже используете JavaScript, на nodejs такой сервис будет гаразда продуктивнее